# Error in Scipy curve fit for more than two parameters

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am quite new to Scipy. I have a data file (https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwz8s2kap2mnwo0/data.dat?dl=0) and want to fit the function a*exp(b*x^c). The problem is when I give manually the value of c (say c = 0.75), the code works perfectly, but if I want to find the 'a', 'b' and 'c' from the fit, the code does not work and producing a flat line. Sorry if the problem is too silly. The code reads as:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as math

filename = sys.argv[1]

data = np.loadtxt(filename)

x = np.array(data[:,0])
y = np.array(data[:,1])

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(b*x**c)

params = curve_fit(func, x, y)

[a, b, c] = params[0]

perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(params[1]))

x_new = []
y_new = []

for i in np.linspace(1.00003e-05, 0.10303175629999914, num=1000):
    j = func(i, a, b, c)
    x_new.append(i)
    y_new.append(j)

x1 = np.array(x_new)
y1 = np.array(y_new)

print ("a = ", a, "error = ", perr[0], "error % = ", (perr[0]/a)*100, '\t' "b = ", b, "error = ", perr[1], "error % = ", (perr[1]/b)*100), '\t' "c = ", c, "error = ", perr[2], "error % = ", (perr[2]/c)*100,

#np.savetxt('fit.dat', np.c_[x1, y1])

plt.plot(x, y, label='data')
plt.plot(x1, y1, label = 'a*np.exp(b*x**c)')
plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
plt.ylabel('SRO')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The objective function has many local minima in the space of `(a,b,c)`. You have to specify a better initial guess for scipy to find the global minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exponential equations can be quite sensitive to the non-linear solver's initial parameter estimates. By default, many non-linear solvers - including scipy's curve_fit - use default initial parameter values of 1.0 for these initial parameter estimates if none are supplied, and in this particular case those values were not good initial estimates for your combination of data and equation. Scipy does include a genetic algorithm which can be used to determine the initial parameter estimates, and their implementation requires bounds within which to search. Here is an example graphical solver using the scipy differential_evolution genetic algorithm module for this purpose, note the ranges that I have used for the genetic algorithm to search within. It is much easier to give ranges for the parameters in this way rather than explicit values, though this is not always true it worked here. You will need to change the file path that I used to load the data.

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

filename = '/home/zunzun/Downloads/data.dat'

data = numpy.loadtxt(filename)

xData = numpy.array(data[:,0])
yData = numpy.array(data[:,1])


def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a*numpy.exp(b*x**c)


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    minData = min(minX, minY)
    maxData = min(maxX, maxY)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([-maxData * 10.0, maxData * 10.0]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([-maxData * 10.0, maxData * 10.0]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([-maxData * 10.0, maxData * 10.0]) # search bounds for c

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Thanks, James for the excellent solution which was beyond my thinking. However, your code gives me some erros while working with other data as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 51, in <module>
    fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 746, in curve_fit
    raise RuntimeError("Optimal parameters not found: " + errmsg)
RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800.

Comment: The new data file is here [https://www.dropbox.com/s/diygvn3m3jhi7ww/plot.dat?dl=0]

Comment: Changing all of the "* 10.0" in the parameter search to "* 5000.0" worked for me, of course the genetic algorithm takes a long time to run with the new data file having over 130,000 data points. It would be faster in the future to fit every 500th data point and use those values on the full data set, I tried that and was much faster during testing the new ranges for the genetic algoritm search.

Comment: Ok, It worked! so basically I need to find the suitable range for a different set of data by changing the value in 'parameterBounds'? One more trivial query: these 'a', 'b' and 'c' are the 'best' fit parameters right, that minimize the error in the data?

Comment: In this technique the genetic algorithm searches for initial parameter estimates within the given bounds, so yes. As far as best fit, the purpose of the scatterplot + model curve is to determine if the curve actually looks like a reasonable fit. Bad initial parameters can yield a bad solution in some circumstances, the plot helps verify that this did not happen. With good starting parameters a good solution can be found, true, but it is good to verify that the fitted parameter values produce a reasonably good result.

Comment: Thank you so much for the excellent work, it is indeed very helpful for me.